# Interpolating element as it scrolls through window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to interpolate a percentage as an element moves through the window as you scroll.

Basically, when the top of the element meets the bottom of the window, that returns 0%. When the bottom of the element meets the top of the window, that returns 100%.

So far I can interpolate using the middle of the element, but I can't figure out how to get it to *start at the top and bottom* instead of the middle.

[Heres a Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qze5agqy/3/)

```
$(document).ready(()=>{

  //Element Vars - Test for Element 3
  const $interpolateTarget = $('#element3');
  const elementH = $interpolateTarget.height();
  const elementY = $interpolateTarget.offset().top;

  //Window Vars
  const windowH = $(window).height()
  let scrollY;
  let interpolation;
  let middlePoint;

  $(window).scroll((event)=>{

    scrollY = $(window).scrollTop()
    pctOfWindow = elementH / windowH

    //Calculate middle of element and compare to middle of window
    middleY = elementH / 2 + elementY  - scrollY
    windowMiddleY = windowH / 2
    interpolation = middleY / windowMiddleY / 2

    //Convert to percentage and reverse
    interpolation = (interpolation * 100 - 100 ) * -1

    updateInfo(scrollY, interpolation);
  })
})
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to consider the document height instead of the window height. The following may help you.

```
updateInfo(scrollY, 100 * $(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height()));
```

- **$(document).scrollTop()** : how much is scrolled in the entire document
- **$(document).height()** : actual document height
- **$(document).height() - $(window).height()** : scrollable document height

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm actually looking for the percentage of when the black element is in the window, not the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I figured it out, changed elementH / 2 + elementY  - scrollY to elementH + elementY  - scrollY